# how to show $ sign in the y-axis on the graph value in iphone app

Tags: iphone, graph, string-formatting

I have graph which shows percent sign on value given but i want the $ i am changing to $ in my code but it hides all the value also

```
     -(void)drawHistogramWithItem:(ECGraphItem *)item index:(int)index color:(UIColor *)color
    {
if (index != 0) 
    _histogramStartX += _histogramSpacing + item.width;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_histogramStartX, _xaxisStart.y - _ySpacingScale*item.yValue,item.width, _ySpacingScale*item.yValue);
[color setFill];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
CGContextAddRect(_context,rect);
CGContextDrawPath(_context, kCGPathFillStroke);
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",item.yValue];

[percentage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(_histogramStartX,_xaxisStart.y - _ySpacingScale*item.yValue - 15) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];
[self drawWords:item.name AtPoint:CGPointMake(_histogramStartX + item.width/8 ,_xaxisStart.y + 5)  color:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
```

Comment: do you have tried this `NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f $",item.yValue];` or `NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.1f",item.yValue];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change that:

```
NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",item.yValue];
```

to that:

```
NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f$",item.yValue];
```

It should work. Hope it helps